# your network access was interrupted access to continue close the database

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, ms-access-2007

i created  a windows application using c# and vs2008 and access2007 database .the program runs properly in my computer but when the setup is installed in the client system i get the error "your network access was interrupted access to continue close the database "

Comment: and try checking the error logs on the box or maybe google even.

Comment: its like i try to insert some data and then this thing happens . the code works good at my end .but where as at the clients end i have this probelm

Comment: i tried googling but didn't help :(

Answer (score 0):

Thoughts:

- Assuming the access2007 database is on a network drive... Is the drive mapped to a drive letter?  If so, does that drive always show up 'enabled', or does it ever show 'disconnected'?
- Is more then 1 user trying to access the DB at the same time.  Usually only one user is allowed read/write access, making Access databases unpractical sometimes.
- Does the Client have a wired connection?  Does the network connection appear to perform well (when doing other things)?

Comment: the database is not on a network drive its on the hard disk itself.Its accessed  by a single user.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I faced this same problem, and I was not able to find anything useful in the Internet. I got it SOLVED! so I write here to share my case and solution:

The reason why I was getting this misleading error message was THE USER running my application: My application is a SERVICE, so user is not the one logged on the computer, but, according to the task manager, user is SYSTEM.

My service is written in Java, and it was trying to connect to a MS Access 2007 .accdb database, getting the error message "Your network access was interrupted. To continue close the database and then open it again".

If I run my service changing "log on as" from "local system account" to "this account" and I enter the user & password used to log on Windows, the problem disappears! As you see, it has nothing to do with closing database and opening it again, and it has nothing to do with network access interruption. An ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED (0x5) would have been much much clearer...  ;-)

I hope this hint helps...